# Spring 5 reactive exception handling

Tags: spring, exception, spring-webflux

I'am writing a complex application as an experiment with Spring 5 Webflux. I'm planning to use lot's of techniques in this application. I'm familiar with the "old style" @RestController, but now, I'm writing functional endpoints. E.g. the backend of a company registration service.I was after something like the @ControllerAdvice in the "old world". But I wasn't really able to find anything similar as a reactive equivalent. (Or anything what worked out for me.)

I have a very basic setup. A routing function, a reactive Cassandra repository, a handler and a test class. The repository operation can throw IllegalArgumentException, and I'd like to handle it by returning HTTP Status BadRequest to client. Just as an example of I'm capable to do it. :-) The exception is taken care by the handler class. Here is my code.

**RouterConfig**

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class RouterConfig {

@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(@Autowired CompanyHandler handler) {
    return RouterFunctions.route()
            .nest(path("/company"), bc -> bc
                    .GET("/{id}", handler::handleGetCompanyDataRequest)                     
                    .before(request -> {
                        log.info("Request={} has been received.", request.toString());
                        return request;
                    })
            .after((request, response) -> {
                log.info("Response={} has been sent.", response.toString());
                return response;
            }))
            .build();       
    }
}
```

**CompanyHandler**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CompanyHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveCompanyRepository repository;

    // Handle get single company data request
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handleGetCompanyDataRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        //Some validation ges here

        return repository.findById(Mono.just(uuid))
            .flatMap(this::ok)
            .onErrorResume(IllegalArgumentException.class, e -> ServerResponse.badRequest().build())
            .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> ok (Company c) {
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(c), Company.class));
    }
}
```

**ReactiveCompanyRepository**

```
@Component
public interface ReactiveCompanyRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Company, UUID>{

    Mono<Company> findByName(String name);

    Mono<Company> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

My problem is that **.onErrorResume(IllegalArgumentException.class, e -> ServerResponse.badRequest().build())** is never called and in the test case:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void testGetCompanyExceptionDuringFind() {

    Mockito.when(repository.findById(Mockito.any(Mono.class))).thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException("Hahaha"));       

    WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(routerConfig.route(companyHandler))
        .build()
        .get().uri("/company/2b851f10-356e-11e9-a847-0f89e1aa5554")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isBadRequest()
        .returnResult(Company.class)
        .getResponseBody();
}
```

I always get HttpStatus 500 instead of 400. So it fails.Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test does not represent how a reactive API is supposed to behave. If such a repository throws an exception directly, I'd consider that a bug a report that to the maintainers.

When a reactive API returns a reactive type like `Mono` or `Flux`, it is expected that all errors are not thrown directly but actually sent as messages in the reactive pipeline.

In this case, your test case should probably be more like:

```
Mockito.when(repository.findById(Mockito.any(Mono.class)))
   .thenReturn(Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Hahaha")));
```

With that, the 
`onError...` operators in Reactor will handle those error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown by the repository service: `repository.findById(Mono.just(uuid))`

Handling the exceptions throw by the validation are fine, I can do that.

Comment: Could you provide more details in your code snippets about that? I can't seem to understand if you're giving it a UUID or why the exception is thrown. Do you have a stacktrace to share as well?

Comment: Just updated the test case. Sorry, I pasted in the wrong test case at first time. Let me know if you need more explanation. I think that makes it more understandable.

Comment: Thanks, will test that when I get home... :-)

Comment: Thanks again. It's OK now. I'm bit new to this reactive world... Accepted your answer.